# The best way to handle content in virtual url - php

Tags: php, optimization

I have an application with php in MVC pattern and smarty template engine.
and I dont have any problem with apache and rewrite engine.
and I try to handle the url and load content in my code by this:
I Split the request to `$req` array :

```
... load all libs and function required .

$smarty->display('header.tpl');

// main switch case

switch ($req[0]) {
    case 'index.php':
        require './inc/index.php';
        $smarty->display('index.tpl');
        break;
    case 'list':
        $smarty->display('list.tpl');
        break;
    case 'topic':
        $smarty->display('single.tpl');
        break;
    case 'login':
        require_once './inc/login.php';
        $smarty->display('login.tpl');
        break;

    case 'msg':
        $smarty->assign('msg', $req[1]);
        $smarty->display('message.tpl');
        break;

    default:
        $smarty->display('error.tpl');
        break;
}

$smarty->display('footer.tpl');
```

Now I'm Just think my code is not optimize and unconventional, and too slow,
How I can optimize this code (always the $req[0] is not ASCII) ?

Comment: Well your approach is fine, It's just not done exactly like this, as you found out, the switch case can be quite long. 

How about adding an abstraction layer that deals with routing urls to content? At the bare minimum you could have a hash table(assoc array) of req[0] to tpls. However from my experience smarty is inherently slower than regular php. are you sure the slowness is caused by the switch case?

Comment: I'm not sure but think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and quick way is include by req[0] you need some pattern by files:

```
$fname = './inc/' . $req[0] . '.php';
if (file_exists($fname)) {
include($fname);
}
```